# how to find sum of input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, sum, return-value

Can anyone help me to find sum of input values using JavaScript. The HTML and JavaScript is given below. Thanks in advance

```js
let inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let button=document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
let sum='';
for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
sum+=parseInt(inputs[i].value);
}
console.log(sum);
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button>Find Sum</button>
```

Comment: sum = 0; not sum = '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `sum` as a string and

When you add to sum `sum+=parseInt(inputs[i].value);` input value is being concatenated.

define the `sum` as integer such as 0.

Check out below code:

```js
let inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
let button=document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
let sum=0;
for(let i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
sum+=parseInt(inputs[i].value);
}
console.log(sum);
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<button>Find Sum</button>
```

Comment: Thank You for your code and explained the reason in an understandable way

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculateSum() {
  // Get the values from the input fields
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);

  // Check if the input is valid
  if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
    alert("Please enter valid numbers.");
    return;
  }

  // Calculate the sum
  var sum = num1 + num2;

  // Display the result
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Sum: " + sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<button onclick="calculateSum()">Find Sum</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```